# Одно и то же приложение показывает разный результат?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

Один и тот же код показывает разные результаты на разных ПК. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Ошибок не выводит, но и не выводит данные.
Может ли быть проблема в *Windows* (на одном 10, а на другом 11)
или в браузерах (Яндекс\Google)?

Иногда пишет, что браузер устарел.

````
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
import time
import re

regex = r"price_85d2b9c\s+\w+\D+(?P<price>\d+\s+\d+)"


class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self,url):
        global app
        self.app = QApplication([])
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
        
    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        #self.loadFinished(bool)
        #print("Load Finished")

    def Callable(self,data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()

start = time.perf_counter()

url = "https://www.aviasales.ru/search/PEE0712MOW23121?request_source=search_form&expected_price_currency=rub&expected_price_source=calendar"
client_response = Client(url)
#print(client_response.html)
test_str = client_response.html

prices = []
        
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
        prices.append("{group}".format(group = match.group(groupNum)))
#print(prices)
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Time taken: {end - start:.2f} seconds")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сайт, с которым вы работаете, очень тяжелый. Попробуйте понаблюдать как он грузится.

Обратите внимание, я добавил кнопку, которую кликните после полной загрузки и отображения страницы. Результат работы смотрите и в `textBrowser`-е

```
import sys
import time
import re
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


regex = r"price_85d2b9c\s+\w+\D+(?P<price>\d+\s+\d+)"


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.html = ''
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me - после полной загрузки страницы")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self)
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        lay.addWidget(self.browser)
        
        lay.addWidget(self.textBrowser)

        self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(
            "https://www.aviasales.ru/search/PEE0712MOW23121?request_source=search_form&expected_price_currency=rub&expected_price_source=calendar"))
        
        self.browser.loadStarted.connect(self.loadStartedHandler)
        self.browser.loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinishedHandler)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.page = self.browser.page() 
        self.html = self.page.toHtml(self.Callable)
        
    def Callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
#        print(f'self.html -- {self.html} \n def Callable(self, data):') #        
        self.finditer_regex()
        
    def finditer_regex(self):
        test_str = self.html    
        prices = []
        matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

        for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
            _match = "Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".\
                format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), 
                       match = match.group())
            print(_match)
            self.textBrowser.append(_match)
            
            for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
                groupNum = groupNum + 1
                _group = "\tGroup {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".\
                    format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), 
                           end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum))
                print(_group)
                self.textBrowser.append(_group)
                prices.append("{group}".format(group = match.group(groupNum)))

        print('\n')
        print(*prices, sep='\n') 
        self.textBrowser.append(str(prices))        
    

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def loadStartedHandler(self):
        print(time.time(), ": load started\n")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def loadProgressHandler(self, prog):
        print(time.time(), ":load progress", prog, '\n')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def loadFinishedHandler(self):
        print(time.time(), ": load finished\n")
      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Widget()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, код который вы написали, работает гораздо лучше чем мой, но цены почему-то выводятся не по порядку, вы не знаете в чём может быть проблема? А ещё можно ли дождаться загрузки элемента автоматически без кнопки?

Comment: @qqStardy по ценам не подскажу, в логику не вникал. Дождаться можно, но примерно, после сигнала loadFinished функцию парсинга запускать через какое-то время. Но я думаю, что кнопка только принесет пользу. попробуйте изменить исходные данные и с кнопкой будет веселее. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых странно, что этот код хоть где - то запускается, так как внутри класса в ините на 11 строке вы используете "QApplication", который не импортировали. Т.е. после добавления следующего импорта в начале программы у меня всё запустилось:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

Если это не поможет, то посмотрите, что лежит в переменной `test_str`, вдруг туда почему - то не записывается html код страницы и соответственно дальше ничего не работает. Так же убедитесь, что версия библиотеки на обоих компьютерах совпадает(это удобно сделать через `pip show <название либы>`).

Comment: там есть строка `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication` , но ее не видно, потому что код не правильно отформатирован. Можете отредактировать его код.